# Retrieve a secret from manager and use it in ec2 cfn-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use a secret in the `cfn-init` of a EC2 instance in CloudFormation. Based on [Secrets Manager Secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager) it should not be difficult but what I'm trying is to use it as part of the command, in my case:

```
01_login_in_docker:
          command: !Join
            - ' '
            - - 'docker login -u '
              - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_USERNAME}} '
              - '-p '
              - '{{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}} '
              - 'cloud.canister.io:5000'
```

`docker-info` is a secret stored in my account and therefore I supposedly only need the name to access to the keys, not the ARN.

Reviewing `cfn-init.log` I see that CF is not resolving anything:

> [ERROR] Command 01_login_in_docker (docker login -u  {{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_USERNAME}}  -p  {{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}}  cloud.canister.io:5000) failed

Has anyone tried something similar or could spot where is my problem?

Comment: It looks like what I'm trying to do is not possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589880/dynamic-references-to-specify-secret-manager-values-in-aws-cloudformation

However I cannot comment in that question yet because of my bad reputation :(
@direvus, If you read this, you are not alone

Answer (score -1):

It's not explicitly mentioned, but all the examples use dynamic references as a whole value and not as part of another string. So maybe try passing those as environment variables. It should be a bit more secure too as the logs won't contain the password in the command.

```
    01_login_in_docker:
      command: |
        docker login -u "$DOCKER_ACCOUNT_USERNAME" -p "$DOCKER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD" cloud.canister.io:5000
      env:
        DOCKER_ACCOUNT_USERNAME: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_USERNAME}}'
        DOCKER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:docker-info:SecretString:DOCKER_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}}'
```

Comment: Thanks and indeed your approach is better than mine but yet it does not resolve the key. I have modified the command to dump it in a file instead of login to get the actual value of the env vars and I see them as {{resolve:secretmananager...