# CloudFormation: Dynamic reference to SecretManager value not working for Resource's Tag Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I want to store a secret in AWS secrets manager and retrieve it in a CloudFormation template.
To test it I just put it in the value of a tag -

```
  MainRouteTable:
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: LIVE
        - Key: Name
          Value: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:tvs:SecretString:testname}}'
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
```

After I run the CloudFormation using the template and the environment is up, the value for the tag "Name" is "{{resolve:secretsmanager:tvs:SecretString:testname}}" and not the actual secret stored in testname.
[image]

I have looked all around and can not figure out what is wrong. According to the AWS docs I am doing it properly.

I can retrieve the secret fine from the CLI -

```
aws secretsmanager --region us-east-1 get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxx:secret:tvs-ZVTiDO --query SecretString --output text | jq -r .testname
```

Any suggestions?

I followed the instructions here -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager

Comment: it seems that the `Tag` property does not support dynamic references, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53589880/dynamic-references-to-specify-secret-manager-values-in-aws-cloudformation) question "you can use them inside of function calls (!Sub, !Join, etc.)".

Comment: I was using Tag as an easy way to test to see if AWS secrets was working properly. I tried using it in "MasterUserPassword:" in defining an RDS cluster. It errored with something like unusable format with no other info.
In using it in the Tag -  I was trying to use it in a area that I could see what it was getting to help debug. 

Is there any other place I could use it to try an see if it is getting what i think it should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SecretString` can only be used in few resources and selected properties. **Tags are not supported**. The [supported list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#template-parameters-dynamic-patterns-resources) is:

```
AWS::DirectoryService::MicrosoftAD Password

AWS::DirectoryService::SimpleAD Password

AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup AuthToken

AWS::IAM::User LoginProfile Password

AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream 

RedshiftDestinationConfiguration Password

AWS::OpsWorks::App Source Password

AWS::OpsWorks::Stack CustomCookbooksSource Password

AWS::OpsWorks::Stack RdsDbInstances DbPassword

AWS::RDS::DBCluster MasterUserPassword 

AWS::RDS::DBInstance MasterUserPassword

AWS::Redshift::Cluster MasterUserPassword
```

Comment: That was it - works great. Thanks for the info!! Happy holidays!!!

Comment: A little confused about this. That list is in the "SSM secure string parameters" section in the documenation - i.e. for Parameter Store, not Secrets Manager. Does this answer imply that the same restricted list also applies to Secrets Manager?

Answer (score 0):

as a general rule, secrets will never display in AWS console, e.g. you can't use the im CloudFormation export, tags ect.

Comment: FYI - I was able to test getting the secret and displaying it in describe tags - specifically in GroupDescription same SecurityGroup.  I only did this for test purposes to make sure that I did get it and it was the correct one - then I changed the secret (of course).

Comment: Thanx for letting me know.